# How to insert and print numbers and string in linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm doing an exercise about the linked-list where I just started to learn it. It requires me to input the room number and the event of the hotel but when I try to print the output of both the room number and event it stop the program after I have choose the option of list all rooms from the menu. How can I fix this codes?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0

void insertRoom(int number, char name);
void listRoom(int number, char name);

struct Number {
    int number;
    char name;
    struct Number *ptrnext;
};

struct Number *headptr, *newptr, *currentptr;

int main()
{
    char ch, name;
    int choice=TRUE, number;

    headptr=NULL;
    while(choice==TRUE) { //menu
        printf("\n\ne - Enter room number and event");
        printf("\nl - List all rooms");
        printf("\nx - Exit\n");
        printf("\nEnter choice: ");
        scanf(" %c",&ch);
        switch(ch) { 
            case 'e':insertRoom(number,name);break;
            case 'l':listRoom(number,name);break;
            case 'x': choice=FALSE; break;

            default: printf("\nEnter only one from the above");
        }
    }
 return 0;
}

void insertRoom(int number,char name) {
    newptr=(struct Number *)malloc(sizeof(struct Number));

    printf("\nEnter a number: ");
    scanf("%d",&newptr->number);
    printf("\nEnter name: ");
    scanf(" %[^\n]s",&newptr->name);

    if (headptr==NULL) {
        headptr=newptr;
        newptr->ptrnext=NULL;
    }
    else {
        newptr->ptrnext=headptr;
        headptr=newptr;
    }
}

void listRoom(int number,char name) {
    if (headptr==NULL) {
        printf("\nEmpty list");
        return;
    }
    currentptr=headptr;

    do {
        printf("\n\nRoom number \tEvent");
        printf("\n%d \t%s",currentptr->number,currentptr->name);
        printf("\n");

        currentptr=currentptr->ptrnext;
    } while(currentptr !=NULL);
}
```

Here is the output of the problem:
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWHZe.png)

Comment: Have you stepped through your code in your debugger?  That should let you narrow the problem down to a specific part of your code.  You're more likely to get a good answer when you can provide a short, simplified example.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When you try to implement something new -- such as a linked list -- it is a good idea to implement it *in isolation* as much as possible. Try writing a program that constructs a linked list of `int`, using hard-coded values. Once you have that working perfectly, you can attempt a list of a more complex data type.

Comment: Hint: `char name;` is nowhere *near* what you should be using to store a **string** of characters. You need a sufficiently sized native array or pointer to dynamic memory.

Comment: @WhozCraig Thank you for giving me a hint on that now I can print both output perfectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just give the size for the name of the event when declaring the variable name to solve the problem

```
char name[30];
```